# Restar dos campos de una tabla en mysql PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero calcular el descanso de un chófer, y para ello tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: TABLA]

Lo que quiero hacer es que me calcule para cada conductor, el descanso más grande expresado en Horas.

Para ello tengo que hacer la resta entre la salida y la llegada del viaje anterior.

Por ejemplo, `Salida (id_viaje=20) - Llegada (id_viaje=19)`, pero hay que tener en cuenta que no siempre el `id_viaje` va a ser el número anterior, ya que en medio puede haber un registro para otro conductor.

No se si me he explicado correctamente, cualquier duda intentaré resolverla!

PD: no hagáis caso a los datos de la tabla, simplemente son pruebas, ya se que no tienen sentido!

Comment: ¿Tienes algo de código con lo que poder empezar? ¿Qué has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: La verdad es que no se muy bien como hacerlo ya que soy un poco novato... No se cual es la lógica a seguir..

Comment: Al decir:  _"Lo que quiero hacer es que me calcule para cada conductor, el descanso más grande expresado en Horas."_ no se entiende bien a qué te refieres. A ver si es esto: Quieres saber cuántas horas ha pasado un conductor x sin conducir calculando para ello el tiempo transcurrido entre la hora de salida de su último viaje y la hora  de llegada del penúltimo. No te preocupes si los viajes que quieres calcular no están seguidos en la tabla, puedes filtrar por el id del conductor. Otra cosa: ¿id_viaje apuntaría a trayectos ida y vuelta a los mismos destinos o a destinos que pueden variar ?

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que quiero calcular!! El id_viaje puede ser un viaje con el mismo Origen que Destino, ya que iría a un punto y volvería, pero hay otros que el Origen y el Destino son distintos (la mayoría).

Comment: Lo que yo haría es agregar una tabla que se llamen "descanso" y dentro los campos: id, id_chofer, inicio_descanso, fin_descanso y fecha. Al final del dia sumaria el total de horas trabajas y las horas de descanso y las restaría para que me de el total. Para eso puedes usar inner join, para vincular las dos tablas.

Comment: ¿el calculo lo necesitas en la query ?, ya que puedes hacer el calculo usando PHP también.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que hacer un JOIN de la tabla con sí misma y pedir los viajes de un mismo conductor, restringiendo a que los de la segunda tabla terminen antes de que empiece el viaje siguiente.

No tengo instalado mysql para probarlo pero debiera ser algo como:

```
SELECT a.id_conductor, a.salida, max(b.llegada) 
FROM viajes a JOIN viajes b USING (id_conductor)
WHERE b.llegada<a.salida
GROUP BY a.id_conductor, a.salida
```

o bien

```
SELECT a.id_conductor, a.salida, max(b.llegada) 
FROM viajes a JOIN viajes ON b.id_conductor=a.id_conductor AND b.llegada<a.salida
GROUP BY a.id_conductor, a.salida
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "TU CONSULTA";
$res = $db->query($sql) OR DIE ("ERROR: ".$sql);
While($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $horas_totales = (strtotime($row['llegada']) - strtotime($row['salida']))/3600;
    $horas_descanso = $horas_totales - $horas_conducidas;
    echo $row['id_conductor']."=>";
    echo $horas_totales."=>";
    echo $horas_descanso."<br>";
}
```

Prueba algo así, suponiendo que la columna horas conducidas es un valor entero debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola Pavlo! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que estoy buscando, ya que no deberíamos utilizar el dato de horas de conducción (está en la tabla para otras consultas). Yo lo que quiero es que me salga un número para cada conductor.
Para eso tengo que hacer las restas entre la salida y la llegada anterior, y que me de la mayor, y eso para cada conductor.
Otra vez, muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme!

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo mucho tiempo, pero te comento, que para emepzar no sé si debe ser así o no, pero tus horas de salida y llegada son las mismas para cada conductor. Sé que se hace uso del strtotime que te convierte la fecha en segundos para que puedas trabajarla como valor numérico luego puedes hacer operaciones con ellas. Si no te han dado la solución cuando yo tenga tiempo miraré a ver como hacerlo.

Comment: Si, ya se que algunos datos coinciden, simplemente son resultado de unas pruebas de introducir datos a través de una página, no hay que hacerles mucho caso.
Respecto a lo de strtotime estoy de acuerdo, esa tiene que ser la manera de trabajar con Columnas DateTime!
Esperaré tu solución entonces! Que vaya bien el día!

Comment: He editado la respuesta es lo más que puedo hacer ahora mismo.